# Date.getTime() returns NaN for ISO/Twitter API dates in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date, timestamp

This is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/e8ytkf0n/):

```
var date = "2014-07-23T15:23:12+0000";
var ts = new Date(date).getTime();
console.log(ts);
```

Why does IE11 print `NaN`?

Firefox/Chrome/and other browsers have no problems on printing `1406128992000`.

Comment: I'm guessing the date string is invalid, and getTime from `invalid date` is `NaN`

Comment: Safari returns `NaN` too.

Comment: Your problem is right here `2014-07-23T15:23:12+0000`

Comment: I don't have controls of that data. It becomes from social api/json. How could I do?

Comment: You should be parsing the date somehow, and pass numbers to the `Date` constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from ECMAScript Language Specification, section [Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15):

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based
>   upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is
>   as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`
>   ...
>   `Z` is the time zone offset specified as "Z" (for UTC) or either "+" or "-" followed by a time expression HH:mm

Apparently, you need to add a `:` in the timezone designator. This should work in IE9:

```js
var dateString = "2014-07-23T15:23:12+0000";
var dateStringISO = dateString.replace(/([+\-]\d\d)(\d\d)$/, "$1:$2");
var timestamp = new Date(dateStringISO).getTime();
console.log(dateString, dateStringISO, timestamp);
```

For Twitter dates you can use the same strategy:

```js
var dateString = "Mon Jan 13 16:04:04 +0000 2014";
var dateStringISO = dateString.replace(/^... (...) (..) (........) (...)(..) (....)$/, function(match, month, date, time, tz1, tz2, year) {
  return year + "-" + {
    Jan: "01",
    Feb: "02",
    Mar: "03",
    Apr: "04",
    May: "05",
    Jun: "06",
    Jul: "07",
    Aug: "08",
    Sep: "09",
    Oct: "10",
    Nov: "11",
    Dec: "12"
  }[month] + "-" + date + "T" + time + tz1 + ":" + tz2;
});
var timestamp = new Date(dateStringISO).getTime();
console.log(dateString, dateStringISO, timestamp);
```

Comment: But if fails with every date? Also with date such as "Mon Jan 13 16:04:04 +0000 2014" return NaN.

Comment: It says in the specs that _If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats._ So yes, a particular date format might work in one browser but not in another.

Comment: This is the Twitter format standard in their json results. How do I will parse `Mon Jan 13 16:04:04 +0000 2014`?

Comment: Change it to `Mon, 13 Jan 2014 16:04:04 GMT` using regex replace; this format should work, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: I'm not so able with regex. Can you help me?

Comment: Note: I was have issues with the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS GMT-0600` so I had to switch to using `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-0600` to make the above work.